# jQuery Get Specific Json Data

Tags: jquery, json

usually, I'm using data from my own MySQL but my company decided to use third party API which produce this JSON data :

```
{"ongkir":{
"query":{"city":"444"},
"status":{"code":200,"description":"OK"},
"results":[{"subdistrict_id":"6131","province_id":"11","province":"Jawa Timur","city_id":"444","city":"Surabaya","type":"Kota","subdistrict_name":"Asemrowo"},...
```

and I have this jquery :

```
$.each(json, function(i,o){
subdistric += "<option value="+o.subdistrict_id+">"+o.subdistrict_name+"</option>";});
```

and it fails to display the `<option>` because the JSON data contains prefix which actually I don't need. how get `subdistrict_id` and `subdistrict_name` from `"results"` part of JSON using jquery?

thank you very much for your help

Comment: Does key `ongkir` is common or change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.each(json.ongkir.results, function(i,o){
subdistric += "<option value="+o.subdistrict_id+">"+o.subdistrict_name+"</option>";});
```

Comment: works like a charm, bro!! thanks a lot! i will accept this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

It will be good if you put the html in a variable. Later when you want to add other attributes to it will be easy and code is more readable than string concatenation.

```
var template = "<option value='#VALUE'>#NAME</option>";

$.each(json.ongkir.results, function(i,o){
      subdistric += template.replace("#VALUE", o.subdistrict_id).replace("#NAME",o.subdistrict_name);
});
```